# LINQ query grouping

Tags: .net, linq

I have a problem with LINQ query. Could somebody please help?

There is one table Content with Columns Id (unique), ContentId, Version.
I'd like to get the latest version for each unique Content Id.

So if table is:

```
 - Id, ContentId, Version
 - 1, 1, 1
 - 2, 1, 2
 - 3, 2, 1
```

Then query should return:

```
 - Id, ContentId, Version
 - 2, 1, 2
 - 3, 2, 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
var result= (
        from c in db.Content
        where db.Content
                  .Where (l =>l.ContentId==c.ContentId)
                  .Max (l=>l.Version)==c.Version
        select c
    );
```

Where db is the linq data context

Comment: No problem. @lekso : Remember to up vote the answers you think are good. That gives us all a warm fuzzy feeling :P